# System partially frozen: cannot alt-tab or force-quit, but can login over AFP... how to fix without hard reboot?

Tags: performance

So I was using Safari on my Mac Pro and randomly, for the first time ever, the system became unresponsive, except I can still move the mouse cursor (which is stuck as an I-beam), and I can login to the machine over AFP, browse its drives, etc.

I prefer not to hard reboot my computer. But I cannot alt-tab out of Safari, I cannot force-quit Safari, and I cannot click on any menus or use the Dock. Which is odd because I can still move the mouse cursor.

This is a really weird type of freeze I've never seen before. This machine has been working flawlessly for five years.

Since I was able to login over AFP, is there anything that I can do to resolve this without hard-rebooting the Mac Pro?

Note: I unplugged all USB, DVI, and FW devices (except my TimeMachine drive) and plugged them back in, to no avail.

Comment: does the alt+cmd+esc still works from where ou can quit Safari

Comment: also a look inside your console log could shed some light

Comment: Command-alt-escape does nothing. I tried a different USB keyboard on a different port and still nothing. Tapping power button on the Mac normally tries a soft shutdown but does nothing. Can't open Console but I can open specific logs over the network... which one should I look at?

Comment: You have a different problem than Safari. The alt+cmd+esc should bring up the force quit window.

Comment: I ended up just doing a hard reboot. From system.log, it appears -- big surprise -- Adobe Flash is behind this. crashed.

Comment: Obviously Flash should not be able to totally hose the system like that. But y'know nothing surprises me these days...

Comment: well, you got it going :)